# Struggling to get mongodb-memory-server 8 working with jest

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose, jestjs

I'm trying to get the latest version of `mongodb-memory-server` working with `jest` on a `node` `express` server. I'm trying to follow the guide in the `mongodb-memory-server` documentation (https://nodkz.github.io/mongodb-memory-server/docs/guides/integration-examples/test-runners#jest), but it seems to leave blanks and I can't figure out how to fill them in.

I've made a repo of my best effort to piece it together: https://github.com/jimmythecode/mongodbmemoryserver-guide

I can't find any instructions online except for older versions of `mongodb-memory-server`. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working setup with  "mongodb-memory-server": "^8.5.2" and "jest": "^28.1.0". Please Check

```
import { MongoMemoryServer } from "mongodb-memory-server";
import mongoose from "mongoose";


let mongo: any;
beforeAll(async () => {
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

  mongo = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
  const mongoUri = await mongo.getUri();

  await mongoose.connect(mongoUri);
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections();

  for (let collection of collections) {
    await collection.deleteMany({});
  }
});

afterAll(async () => {
  jest.setTimeout(20000)
  await mongo.stop();
  await mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

Comment: That seems to work, thanks! It's interesting that the line `const mongoUri = await mongo.getUri();` doesn't flag as an error, since it was replaced with a non-async function in the v8 update (see this example: https://nodkz.github.io/mongodb-memory-server/docs/guides/quick-start-guide#normal-server). Also I'm wondering how you manged to put this together since it is quite different from the code in the guide. Kudos for achieving it!

Comment: Also, the test takes 8 seconds to run. Is that normal?

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to get it working and have updated it in this [branch](https://github.com/jimmythecode/mongodbmemoryserver-guide/tree/mongodb-memory-server-guide-now-working), in case it helps anyone.